# How do staff users edit their profiles in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django. I'm working on a website that will only contain users as staff users. I'm the administrator. My plan is to register a user and give him his username and password to log in; I want him only to be able to edit his profile to add more information, not to change existing attributes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have the edit (views/forms)/(viewsets/serializers) validate, pre-save, that the data to be saved only modifies values that are falsy in the instance to be edited.

Doing that is not hard, so I'm not going to write the code to do so here.

Comment: I'm using APIViews and staff can update their profile in Django admin, How can I achieve that Thank You

Comment: Then you'll need to override the form used by your staff admin.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this I tried but it's not working